# How to fix java RuntimeException: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml'?

Tags: solr

I used Ubuntu 8.10 as the Solr server OS, and set:

```
solr.solr.home=home/huenzhao/search/tomcat6/bin/solr.
```

When I run the tomcat（The tomcat and the Solr that I used running on windows XP has no problem, there has error as :

```
HTTP Status 500 - Severe errors in solr configuration. Check your log files for more detailed information on what may be wrong. If you want solr to continue after configuration errors, change: <abortOnConfigurationError>false</abortOnConfigurationError> in null ------------------------------------------------------------- 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or 'home/huenzhao/search/tomcat6/bin/solr/conf/', cwd=/home/huenzhao/search/tomcat6/bin at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openResource(SolrResourceLoader.java:194) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openConfig(SolrResourceLoader.java:162) at org.apache.solr.core.Config.<init>(Config.java:100) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.<init>(SolrConfig.java:113) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.<init>(SolrConfig.java:70) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:117) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:69) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:275) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:397) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:108) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3696) at
```

Anybody knows how to do?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I suspect you just need a leading slash to indicate that your directory name is absolute rather than relative:

```
solr.solr.home=/home/huenzhao/search/tomcat6/bin/solr
```

If that's not it, please post where your `solrconfig.xml` file lives.

On a Windows machine, update the `solr/home` property in `solr/web.xml` along these lines:

```
<env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>solr/home</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-value>C:/solr</env-entry-value>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
</env-entry>
```

Comment: But did you try with the absolute directory instead of the relative directory?

Comment: Yes, I take your advice and try with the absolute directory, and it work. Thanks very much!

Comment: where shold be solrconfig.xml file must be?

Comment: @DivyangShah: It sounds like it should be in the solr configuration directory, based on the documentation. It's not really clear what the context of your question is though... if you've tried following the documentation (and this answer) and you're still stuck, you may want to ask a new question.

Comment: thanks for reply, problem solved out. The problem was the user to whom permission was provided was different than what needed.

Answer (score 3):

I was running into the same problem both on a windows machine at home and on a hosted VPS linux machine. The solution turned out to be I didn't actually have a directory conf in webapps/solr and this not correct path to solrconfig.xml

The path is to be configured in solr.xml which should reside either inside 
your-tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/

or on the class path.

Answer (score 3):

I have update property of solr/home from  solr/web.xml as below ; and it is worked.

```
 <env-entry>
       <env-entry-name>solr/home</env-entry-name>
       <env-entry-value>C:/solr</env-entry-value>
       <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    </env-entry>
```

Comment: This actually solve my problem when i was trying a sample solr example as per the tutorial and getting the above error. Quiet strange though that this is never mentioned as an alert point in the Solr Tutorial document. :(

Answer (score 2):

for solving this you have to add 
1. Download the Solr package form the following path
http://www.trieuvan.com/apache//lucene/solr/3.1.0/apache-solr-3.1.0.zip

1. Extract it and copy the file 'dist/apache-solr-3.1.0.war' to Tomcat's webapps folder as solr.war
2. Make a folder c:/solr (Which will be our Solr home and all the index will live here) and copy the folder contents of 'examples/solr/' from extracted files to this location
3. Edit the file catalina.bat and apply the following patch (you can also do it manually, just adding a line)

   @@ -84,7 +84,8 @@
    rem $Id: catalina.bat 1040546 2010-11-30 14:47:34Z markt $
    rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

   -
   +rem Adding solr home path
   +set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dsolr.solr.home=c:/solr

and install tomcat windows service(which is in tomcat/bin)
Try this....

Answer (score 1):

#### Windows

In my `solr.xml` I set `solr/home` to `d:\tomcat 6.0`.

And copied the contents of conf folder which comes as part of solr extract into `d:\tomcat 6.0\conf` folder.

It will surely work for you. please note this is a windows based solution accordingly you need to try for other systems.