# How to fix java RuntimeException: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath?

Tags: solr, centos, tomcat5.5

I'm having issues setting up Solr as Tomcat service in CentOS. I’m using solr 3.3.0 which should be working with Tomcat 5.5 installed from cPanel. The error I was getting is:

> Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/home/sampleuser/public_html/apache-solr/example/solr/./conf/', cwd=/usr/local/jakarta/apache-tomcat-5.5.33/bin

I saw other people having similar issues. I googled and tried to apply all of the approaches. However nothing worked for me so far.

I did the following:

1. Copied `solr.war` to `tomcat/webapps`
2. Restarted Tomcat Service
3. Edited `/usr/local/jakarta/tomcat/webapps/solr/WEB-INF/web.xml` as:

   ```
   <env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>solr/home</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-value>/home/sampleuser/public_html/apache-solr/example/solr</env-entry-value>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
   </env-entry>
   ```
4. Created `solr.xml` in `/usr/local/jakarta/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost` as:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
   <Context docBase="/usr/local/jakarta/tomcat/webapps/solr.war" debug="0" crossContext="true">
     <Environment name="solr/home" type="java.lang.String"    
          value="/home/sampleuser/public_html/apache-solr/example"override="true"/>
   </Context>
   ```
5. Edited tomcat startup script at `etc/init.d` (not sure if I had to do it at all) with:

`export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dsolr.solr.home=/home/sampleuser/public_html/apache-solr/example/solr"`

Below is the complete error log from catalina.err:

```
Oct 9, 2011 7:35:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stop 
INFO: Stopping service Catalina 
Oct 9, 2011 7:35:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log 
INFO: SessionListener: contextDestroyed() 
Oct 9, 2011 7:35:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log 
INFO: ContextListener: contextDestroyed() 
Oct 9, 2011 7:35:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log 
INFO: SessionListener: contextDestroyed() 
Oct 9, 2011 7:35:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log 
INFO: ContextListener: contextDestroyed() 
Oct 9, 2011 7:35:06 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol destroy 
INFO: Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080 
Oct 9, 2011 7:35:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init 
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/local/jdk/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/local/jdk/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib 
Oct 9, 2011 7:35:23 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol init 
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080 
Oct 9, 2011 7:35:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load 
INFO: Initialization processed in 2875 ms 
Oct 9, 2011 7:35:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start 
INFO: Starting service Catalina 
Oct 9, 2011 7:35:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start 
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/5.5.33 
Oct 9, 2011 7:35:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost start 
INFO: XML validation disabled 
Oct 9, 2011 7:35:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor 
WARNING: A docBase /usr/local/jakarta/tomcat/webapps/solr.war inside the host appBase has been specified, and will be ignored 
Oct 9, 2011 7:35:25 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader locateSolrHome 
INFO: Using JNDI solr.home: /home/sampleuser/public_html/apache-solr/example/solr 
Oct 9, 2011 7:35:25 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader <init>
INFO: Solr home set to '/home/sampleuser/public_html/apache-solr/example/solr/' 
Oct 9, 2011 7:35:25 PM org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter init 
INFO: SolrDispatchFilter.init() 
Oct 9, 2011 7:35:25 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader locateSolrHome 
INFO: Using JNDI solr.home: /home/sampleuser/public_html/apache-solr/example/solr 
Oct 9, 2011 7:35:25 PM org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer initialize 
INFO: looking for solr.xml: /home/sampleuser/public_html/apache-solr/example/solr/solr.xml 
Oct 9, 2011 7:35:25 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader locateSolrHome 
INFO: Using JNDI solr.home: /home/sampleuser/public_html/apache-solr/example/solr 
Oct 9, 2011 7:35:25 PM org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer <init>
INFO: New CoreContainer: solrHome=/home/sampleuser/public_html/apache-solr/example/solr/ instance=1537767228 
Oct 9, 2011 7:35:25 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader <init>
INFO: Solr home set to '/home/sampleuser/public_html/apache-solr/example/solr/' 
Oct 9, 2011 7:35:26 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader <init>
INFO: Solr home set to '/home/sampleuser/public_html/apache-solr/example/solr/./' 
Oct 9, 2011 7:35:26 PM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log 
SEVERE: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/home/sampleuser/public_html/apache-solr/example/solr/./conf/', cwd=/usr/local/jakarta/apache-tomcat-5.5.33/bin 
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openResource(SolrResourceLoader.java:268) 
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openConfig(SolrResourceLoader.java:234) 
        at org.apache.solr.core.Config.<init>(Config.java:141) 
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.<init>(SolrConfig.java:131) 
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:435) 
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:316) 
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:133) 
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:94) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:221) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:302) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:78) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3666) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4258) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:760) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:740) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:544) 
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:634) 
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:561) 
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:496) 
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1203) 
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:319) 
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:120) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1022) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:736) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:448) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:700) 
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552) 
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) 
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) 
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295) 
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) 
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) 
        at org.apache.commons.daemon.support.DaemonLoader.start(DaemonLoader.java:219) 

Oct 9, 2011 7:35:26 PM org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter init 
INFO: user.dir=/usr/local/jakarta/apache-tomcat-5.5.33/bin 
Oct 9, 2011 7:35:26 PM org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter init 
INFO: SolrDispatchFilter.init() done 
Oct 9, 2011 7:35:26 PM org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrServlet init 
INFO: SolrServlet.init() 
Oct 9, 2011 7:35:26 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader locateSolrHome 
INFO: Using JNDI solr.home: /home/sampleuser/public_html/apache-solr/example/solr 
Oct 9, 2011 7:35:26 PM org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrServlet init 
INFO: SolrServlet.init() done 
Oct 9, 2011 7:35:26 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader locateSolrHome 
INFO: Using JNDI solr.home: /home/sampleuser/public_html/apache-solr/example/solr 
Oct 9, 2011 7:35:26 PM org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrUpdateServlet init 
INFO: SolrUpdateServlet.init() done
```

When I copy the missing path via shell I was able to navigate just fine. Seem like Tomcat cannot locate the `solrconfig.xml`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198282/http-status-500-java-lang-runtimeexception-cant-find-resource-solrconfig-xm)

Comment: It could be a typo: `value="/home/sampleuser/public_html/apache-solr/example"override="true"`. No space between properties.

Answer (score 3):

First off: you don't need to #3 ***and*** #4 ***and*** 5.  #3 isn't really recommended unless you are explicitly customizing the solr.war. #4 and #5 are two different ways to do the same thing - use whichever one is most convenient for you (JNDI vs system properties)

Second: please note that while #3 and #5 are consistent, in #4 you actually specify a different Solr home dir (the parent dir of what you really want)

Third: I think the crux of your problem is file permissions.

The logging is a bit confusing due to [SOLR-3264](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3264) which causes "instanceDirs" for each core to be refered to erroneously as "Solr Home" but what seems to be happening is that it can't find (or read) your "/home/sampleuser/public_html/apache-solr/example/solr/solr.xml" so it's going into legacy "Single Core" mode where it assumes that you want to use your Solr Home dir as an instanceDir for a (single) Solr Core -- so it then looks for "/home/sampleuser/public_html/apache-solr/example/solr/solrconf.xml" and if it can't find (or read) that file it gives up.

So depending on whether your main concern is that you actually have a solr.xml (pointing to alternate instanceDirs) hat it's not finding, or if you actually have a solrconfig.xml file where it's looking, check the file permissions of those files (and their directories), and make sure they are readable by the effective user of your tomcat server.

(FWIW: Solr 3.6 and up will have [better logging when solr.xml is not found and legacy mode is used](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?rev=1304126&view=rev), and I've opened [SOLR-3266](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3266) to pursue better ways of logging/erroring on unreadable files in the future)