# How to fix java IOException: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath?

Tags: apache, tomcat, solr, lucene

I was trying to install Apache Solr 4.0.0 with apache Tomcat, but it is giving an error like this:

> SolrCore Initialization Failures
>   collection1: java.io.IOException:java.io.IOException: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or 'solr\collection1\conf/', cwd=C:\apps\tomcat-solr\apache-tomcat-7.0.35\bin

There are no SolrCores running. 
Using the Solr Admin UI currently requires at least one SolrCore.

After this I have installed apache solr 3.6.2 and it working perfectly well. I still cannot understand why i am not able to use solr 4.0.0 with the same server configuration.

I hope you will be able to tell me the mistake i have committed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix java RuntimeException: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734689/how-to-fix-java-runtimeexception-cant-find-resource-solrconfig-xml-in-classp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory structure changed in Solr 4.0. Have a look at the one in the example/solr directory. You will see that Solr 4 now has **collection1** directory inside that and conf directory is now one level lower inside that. That's basically what the error message said.

If you don't like that, I think you can change it by putting solr.xml with the single core definition in it and directory paths setup the way you like it.