# Absolute Paths in solr.xml configuration using Tomcat6 on windows

Tags: windows, tomcat, configuration, solr, multicore

We have a multicore SOLR setup with two cores, one for site and one for catalog data.

Inside `solr.xml` the core config is as follows;

```
<cores adminPath="/admin/cores">
    <core name="catalog" instanceDir="e:\SolrInstances\catalog" />
    <core name="sites" instanceDir="e:\SolrInstances\sites" />
</cores>
```

`e:\` is a mapped/mounted network drive that is regularly backed up.

However, when we try to access a core we get a nasty stack trace

```
Jul 17, 2013 8:28:00 PM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
SEVERE: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or 'e:\SolrInstances\sites\conf/', cwd=C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openResource(SolrResourceLoader.java:268)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openConfig(SolrResourceLoader.java:234)
    at org.apache.solr.core.Config.<init>(Config.java:141)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.<init>(SolrConfig.java:131)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:435)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:316)
```

We initially had the cores in the Tomcat root with relative paths during development, and it worked fine, but moving to a mapped/mounted network drive with absolute paths does not work.

And `solrconfig.xml` does exist in both `e:\SolrInstances\sites\conf` and `e:\SolrInstances\catalog\conf`and the solr user has permissions to those directories.

Does anyone have any clues?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix java RuntimeException: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734689/how-to-fix-java-runtimeexception-cant-find-resource-solrconfig-xml-in-classp)

Answer (score 0):

Try the UNC path instead, see: http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Windows#Q6