# Solr 4.3 config error in eclipse

Tags: jsf, solr

I have integrated solr 4.3 to my web app and added all dependencies. when i run my app on tomcat through Eclipse juno i get the following error.

Note: if i deploy my app.war directly to webapp dir of tomcat it seems to work fine.

HTTP Status 500 - {msg=SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init failure: Could not load config for solrconfig.xml,trace=org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init failure: Could not load config for solrconfig.xml at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.getCore(CoreContainer.java:1212) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:248) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:155) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123) at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99) at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1008) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load config for solrconfig.xml at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:919) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:984) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$2.call(CoreContainer.java:597) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$2.call(CoreContainer.java:592) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) ... 3 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or 'solr/collection1/conf/', cwd=/home/kumarkailash at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openResource(SolrResourceLoader.java:337) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openConfig(SolrResourceLoader.java:302) at org.apache.solr.core.Config.(Config.java:122) at org.apache.solr.core.Config.(Config.java:92) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.(SolrConfig.java:119) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:916) ... 11 more ,code=500}

type Status report

message {msg=SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init failure: Could not load config for solrconfig.xml,trace=org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init failure: Could not load config for solrconfig.xml at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.getCore(CoreContainer.java:1212) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:248) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:155) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123) at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99) at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1008) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load config for solrconfig.xml at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:919) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:984) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$2.call(CoreContainer.java:597) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$2.call(CoreContainer.java:592) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) ... 3 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or 'solr/collection1/conf/', cwd=/home/kumarkailash at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openResource(SolrResourceLoader.java:337) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openConfig(SolrResourceLoader.java:302) at org.apache.solr.core.Config.(Config.java:122) at org.apache.solr.core.Config.(Config.java:92) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.(SolrConfig.java:119) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:916) ... 11 more ,code=500}

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.40

please help. thanks

Comment: how are you setting the solr home property to indicate where the config are ?

Comment: Im currently setting the solr home in tomcat catalina.sh file. export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dsolr.solr.home=/home/kumarkailash/solr-4.3.0/example/solr"

Comment: does the setting apply when you start it from eclipse ?? or can you try setting it in web.xml itself ?

Comment: NO the setting does not get applied when i start it form eclipse. can u please tell me how to set it in web.xml?

Comment: check for the commented solr.home tag and uncomment it and set the correct value in there

Comment: Thnak you soo much. I added env path in my web.xml and directed it to point to solr home. It seems to work fine.

Comment: cool .. added it as an answer and you can accept it. thanks.-

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198282/http-status-500-java-lang-runtimeexception-cant-find-resource-solrconfig-xm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems the solr.home is missing.
You can add the solr.home entry to the web.xml itself.
Uncomment the line and populate correct values :-

```
<env-entry>
   <env-entry-name>solr/home</env-entry-name>
   <env-entry-value>/put/your/solr/home/here</env-entry-value>
   <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
</env-entry>
```